# How do you differentiate $f(x) = x+\sqrt{x}+4$, using the definition of a derivative?

Tags: calculus

Obviously $\dfrac{d}{dx} (x+\sqrt{x}+4) = 1 +\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$. But my problem is with using the precise definition of a limit, namely:
$\frac{d}{{dx}}f\left( x \right) = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{{f\left( {x + h} \right) - f\left( x \right)}}{h}$.

How would you differentiate $f(x) = x+\sqrt{x}+4$, using the precise definition of a derivative?

Comment: have you tried evaluating the quantity? what difficulty did you face?

Answer (score 3):

\begin{align*}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} &= \frac{(x+h)+\sqrt{x+h}+4-(x+\sqrt{x}+4)}{h} \\
&= \frac{h + \sqrt{x+h}-\sqrt{x}}{h} \\
&= 1+\frac{\sqrt{x+h}-\sqrt{x}}{h} \\
&= 1 + \frac{(\sqrt{x+h}-\sqrt{x})(\sqrt{x+h}+\sqrt{x})}{h(\sqrt{x+h}+\sqrt{x})}\\
&= 1 + \frac{(x+h)-x}{h(\sqrt{x+h}+\sqrt{x})} \\
&= 1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{x+h}+\sqrt{x}}
\end{align*}

Comment: I'd say the key step was when you multiplied the top and the bottom by $\sqrt{x+h} + \sqrt{x}$, which led to a nice simplification. It might not seem like an obvious thing to do, but, this is a standard trick that is sometimes taught in high school algebra courses.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to approach it:

\begin{align*}
f(x) = x + \sqrt{x} + 4 = \left(\sqrt{x} + \frac{1}{2}\right)^{2} + \frac{15}{4}
\end{align*}
whence we conclude that:
\begin{align*}
\frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x - a} & = \frac{1}{x - a}\left[\left(\sqrt{x} + \frac{1}{2}\right)^{2} - \left(\sqrt{a} + \frac{1}{2}\right)^{2}\right]\\\\
& = \frac{1}{x - a}\left(\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{a}\right)\left(\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{a} + 1\right)\\\\
& = \frac{\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{a} + 1}{\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{a}}
\end{align*}

Consequently, it results that (for $a > 0$):
\begin{align*}
f'(a) = \lim_{x\to a}\frac{\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{a} + 1}{\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{a}} = \frac{2\sqrt{a} + 1}{2\sqrt{a}} = 1 + \frac{1}{2\sqrt{a}}
\end{align*}

Hopefully this helps!